# How can we create an empty Active Record Relation and fill it with an each do block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have the following code :

```
@memberlist = []

    @memberlistpage = @memberlist.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

    Member.all.includes(:bronze, :silver, :gold).each do |member|
        if member.bronze
            if member.bronze.skillas.to_s.include?(@assessor.id.to_s)
                @memberlist << member
            end

            if member.bronze.serviceas.to_s.include?(@assessor.id.to_s)
                @memberlist << member
            end

            if member.bronze.precreationas.to_s.include?(@assessor.id.to_s)
                @memberlist << member
            end

            if member.bronze.ajourneyas.to_s.include?(@assessor.id.to_s)
                @memberlist << member
            end
        end
     end
```

With that code im searching and adding `Members` to an array. I need to add it to an Active Record Relation so I can use `pagination` on it.

The structures :

Table name: members

```
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  awardunit_id    :integer
#  name            :string(255)
#  address         :string(255)
#  district        :string(255)
#  gender          :string(255)
#  dob             :date
#  contact         :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  operator        :string(255)
#  entrylvl        :string(255)
#  guardianname    :string(255)
#  guardianaddress :string(255)
#  guardiancontact :string(255)
#  guardianemail   :string(255)
#  currentaward    :string(255)
#  disabled        :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
```

Table name: bronzes

```
    #  id            :integer          not null, primary key
    #  member_id     :integer
    #  regdate       :date
    #  expdate       :date
    #  compldate     :date
    #  skill         :text
    #  skillas       :integer
    #  service       :text
    #  serviceas     :integer
    #  precreation   :text
    #  precreationas :integer
    #  ajourney      :text
    #  ajourneyas    :integer
    #  created_at    :datetime
    #  updated_at    :datetime
```

Comment: Can you post the table structures and models of `member`, `bronze`, `skillas`

Comment: @shiva Just added the structures :)

Answer (score 0):

`Member.none` will return an empty active record relation object.  Instead of getting all the members and looping through each one to get what you want, how about you set up a query for each one and then use [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Queries would easily do this job

**Ex:**

```
Member.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bronze on member.id=bronze.member_id").where("bronze.skillas like '%#{@assessor.id}%'").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Depending table structures you can add multiple joins and where clause conditions in the above query for the remaining values.

Comment: Its giving me this error : "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...mbers.id=bronzes.member_id WHERE (bronzes.skillas like '%198..."

Comment: post the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to change your request getting data to something like this

```
@memberlist = []
Bronze.all.each do | bronze |
  @memberlist << bronze.members.all
end
```

This may not works but shows what i mean. Bronze is related to User with has_many I guess.
So you get for `Bronze.first.all.map(&:user_id)` all user_id's?

Comment: Actually one member have only one Bronze :)

Comment: All members doesn't have bronze... The ones who have only have one bronze

Comment: @EApubs are the types of metals so different in table structure that it is necessary to use separated tables?

Comment: Actually one member have three awards... Bronze, Silver and Gold. Gold have different set of fields. Only one can be there per member at a time. So, to make things easy I made them into separate tables :D